# Superagent error handling React Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, superagent

I am working on this API React App. I am using Superagent to get the API request. But I have trouble handling the error when there is no response. I get this Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unsuccessful HTTP response. I have tried to put all the code inside a try-catch, but that would not do the job still get the error. 
This is my code:

```
handleClick() {
var searchWord = this.refs.search.value;
var url = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/name/" + searchWord + "?fullText=true";
Request.get(url).then((response) => {
  var res = JSON.parse(response.text);
  this.setState({
    name:res[0].name,
    flag:res[0].flag,
    capital:res[0].capital,
  });
});
}
```

I want to handle the error, to print out to the user that there was nothing found or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should do it.

```
Request.get(url)
  .then((response) => {
    var res = JSON.parse(response.text);
    this.setState({
    name:res[0].name,
    flag:res[0].flag,
    capital:res[0].capital,
  })
.catch((err) => {console.log(err)});
```

Basically you append a `catch()` after the `then()` method.